# WordPress Gutenberg get page template value when post updated?

Tags: rest-api, save-post, block-editor

I need to get the page template name when the post is saved. It fails in save_post hook as `$_POST('page_template')` is not available. Gutenberg saves post via the REST API and uses `WP_REST_Post_Controller->handle_template` to save page template data. And like I said it does not make `$_POST('page_template')` available in save_post. It also looks like `WP_REST_Post_Controller->handle_template` fires after `save_post` hook. 
I need to find a way to check the the page template being saved so that I can change the value being saved if needed. 
Thanks

Comment: Is this a Gutenberg bug or is there a work around?

Answer (score 2):

So I found a solution. There are 4 hooks that can be used to accomplish this depending on the exact needs. 
The hooks are from `wp-includes/meta.php` in functions `update_metadata()` and `add_metadata()`.

Hooks:
`update_postmeta`
`updated_postmeta`
`add_post_meta`
`added_post_meta`

These are called at different states and from the names it is pretty self self explanatory. `add_post_meta` and `update_postmeta` are called right before any DB changes and `updated_postmeta` and `added_post_meta` are called right after any changes to the DB.

Example:

```
//Example usage for updated and added.
 function page_template_check( $meta_id, $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value ) {

    // Stop if not the correct meta key
    if ( $meta_key != '_wp_page_template' ) {
        return false;
    }

    //Do stuff here

};

add_action( 'added_post_meta', 'page_template_check', 10, 4 ); //after add
add_action( 'updated_postmeta', 'page_template_check', 10, 4 ); //after update
```